# semaphore for a datarow

Tags: asp.net

I am writing a web application that allows the user basic CRUD operations against a database.   The tables that are being updated have less than 200 records and there may be multiple users using this applications there is a need for some sort of locking mechanism to avoid the 2 users from overwriting each others changes.

I have looked into semaphores but that seems to only limit the number of users executing the same code.  In my data layer I have a class file for each table so I can certainly employ this on a specific table's class file but can I somehow limit the locking to the key fields?

Comment: Does your database not support locking? Why do it in code?

Comment: I'm sure it does but, unless I am forgetting something, that wont stop user 1 and 2 from loading the same record into the webpage (select query), each editing and submitting changes (update query), each thinking their changes are the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a proper SQL implementation along with ASP .Net, why dont you use transactions to achieve this? [Check it out here.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26657)

Additionally, you can also read up on [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404102.aspx) to see if that is what you need. Basically, before saving a value, the user checks if the value in a particular field is the same as it was when he first read it. If the value is the same, it is assumed that noone else has overwritten it, and the new value is saved to the DB; if the values are not the same, a warning message is returned instead.

Comment: I am connecting to a DB2 database using ODBC, if that helps.

Comment: Optimistic concurrency (hadn't heard that term before) is the approach I am leaning towards.  Right now I am getting the data from the database and putting it into a DTO and storing that in a session variable to compare against the database again before submitting changes.

Comment: Optimistic concurrency can be achieved with minimum fuss if you use a TableAdapter using the configuration wizard. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404102.aspx] (search for "Creating a Data Access Layer that Supports Optimistic Concurrency"). In fact, it is a built in property. However, it comes with the disadvantages of using an Adapter in the first place, namely that a change in DB schema / SPs isn't reflected automatically in the Adapter. However, if you already have a set of Stored Procedures that are being used elsewhere, I think this is your best option :)